# Basis which makes TWO linear transformation diagonalised at once

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Find a basis $\gamma$ with respect to which both of the following lienar transformations on $\mathbb{R^3}$ become diagionalised (the matrices below are the matrices with respect to the standard basis):

$$S=\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
    $$

and $$T=\begin{bmatrix}
        2 & -1 & 2 \\
        -1 & 2 & 2 \\
        2 & 2 & -1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

I found a basis of eigenvectors for S and another one for T but they are not the same, how should I proceed?

Comment: Hint:  Does $ST = TS$?

Comment: **Hint:** $T$ has distinct eigenvalues, so any eigenvector of $T$ is also an eigenvector of $S$

Comment: @OOmnomnomnom: Maxima says $T$ has only $2$ eigenvalues, $-3$ and $3$.

Comment: 3 is a repeated eigenvalue

Comment: Could you further you explanation please, I am missing pieces of the jigsaw puzzle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Try the transformation matrix (or it's inverse depending on what you call the transformation matrix)
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & -2\\
1 & -1 &-2\\
-2& 0 &-2\\
\end{bmatrix}$$